# Why do I get this Syntax error in Python Shell but no Pycharm IDE?

Tags: python, syntax

Error when put into Python Shell 3.7 Windows 64bit.

```
def square(number):
    square_of_number = (number * number)  
    return square_of_number  

user_input = int(input("What number do you want to square?"))

result = square(user_input)

print("That number squared is {}".format(result))
```

> ```
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax at user_input line
> ```

When I run this in the `Pycharm` IDE the code works fine. Why does it not work in Python Shell?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work in the shell"? Do you mean in the REPL, or in a shell script? It should work in both...

Comment: Shell script. Somehow it gives me errors. Tried it with VB and no errors either.

Comment: VB? Can you copy the full `SyntaxError` into the question exactly as it is output to your screen?